# Displaying Image attachments of child posts in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, types, posts

Can someone kindly provide me with a loop that will output the Image attachments of child posts in Wordpress on a parent post's single.php

**My child post slug: investment-updates**

What I have now to pull the title is this:

```
<?php
//children
  $child_posts = get_posts(array(
                   'numberposts' => -1, 
                   'orderby' => 'name', 
                   'post_type' => 'investment-updates',
                   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpcf_belongs_investment_id',
            'value'   => $post->ID,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
  )); 


?>


<?php  foreach ($child_posts as $child_post){
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title($child_post->ID) . '</li>';
  } ?>
```